# How to find questions with particular tag (Tag synonyms make it difficult)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was searching for posts with Tag [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns) but seems like due to tag synonyms handling, all posts with [design-pattern](/questions/tagged/design-pattern) are displayed.

[Search URL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:649524+[patterns])

I have following questions
1. How to find questions with [patterns](/questions/tagged/patterns)
2. In my profile, both tags, patterns, and design-patterns are displayed. Why both are displayed (and not the main one)?

Answer (score 3):

That is how the system is supposed to work.

They are made synonyms because it's agreed that A means the exact same thing as B.

If they decided to keep only A and threw away B, then anything that would have been tagged B would be tagged A.

The end result being, you would still see the exact same subset of questions. The only thing that has changed is that you know about it.

Comment: Other thing that has changed is that even though the same posts are shown for all the tag synonyms, but not the same score.